# How to dynamically plot Y-Axis scale according min max value?

Tags: highcharts

We have scenario as explained below.

1: Multiple lines we plot as line chart.
2: We also plot bars in same graph.

Expected result :

The bars should be rendered to max value of lines plotted. For example id my lines contain max value 50 and bar is of 150 in this case bar should plot to 50 only and on hover of bar it should display value 15.

Thanks.

Comment: mention the frameworks you are using for us to be able to help you... You want css based solution only... or js (some framework or base)... without that question is not very specific

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? We can help if you hit a roadblock, but we're not here to do your work for you

Comment: The lines points and bars are printed according to your data data, so could you replicate the example as live demo ?

Comment: You will have to provide the appropriate data values to your bars to make them plot at the same point as the lines.  But why would you want to confuse your users in such a way?

Comment: Thanks all, it resolved